# i want to get all related images corresponding to the image selected

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to get all the related pics corresponding to the pic selected....
here is my view page

```
<?php foreach($detail as $row){?>                                       
<img class="primary-image" ima="<?php echo base_url();?>images/<?php echo $row->image;?>" src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/<?php echo $row->image;?>" alt="" />                                          
<?php }?>
```

my view page is this

```
<?php foreach($detail as $row){?>
                                    <!-- product start -->
                                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                                        <div class="two-product">
                                            <!-- single-product start -->
                                            <div class="single-product">
                                            <!--    <span class="sale-text">Sale</span>-->

                                                <div class="product-img">

                                                    <a href="#">

                                                        <img class="primary-image" ima="<?php echo base_url();?>images/<?php echo $row->image;?>" src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/<?php echo $row->image;?>" alt="" />
                                                        <img class="secondary-image" ima="<?php echo base_url();?>images/<?php echo $row->image;?>" src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/<?php echo $row->image;?>" alt="" />
                                                    </a>
                                                    <div class="action-zoom">
                                                        <div class="add-to-cart">
                                                            <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>images/<?php echo $row->image ?>" data-toggle="modal-image" title="Quick View"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="actions">
                                                        <div class="action-buttons">


                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                <!--    <div class="price-box">
                                                        <span class="new-price">$110.00</span>
                                                    </div>-->
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="product-content">
                                                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>roxcontrol/product_details/<?php echo $row->id;?>"><?php echo $row->title;?></a></h2>
                                                    <p><?php echo $row->description;?></p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- single-product end -->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                <?php }?>
```

my control page looks like this....

```
public function product_details($p_id)
{
    $data['active_mn']='product_details';
    $data['product']=$this->roxmodel->get_product_details($p_id);
    $id = $this->input->post['category_id'];
    $data['detail']=$this->roxmodel->get_related_image($id,4,0);
    var_dump($data['detail']);
    $this->load->view('product_details',$data);
}
```

my model page looks like this

```
public function get_related_image($id,$limit,$offset)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('gallery');
    $this->db->join('category','category.id=gallery.category_id');
    $this->db->where('category_id',$id);
    $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

here is my table-gallery(table name)

```
id     image                category_id         
93   img1455604030.jpg       10              
94   img1455605183.jpg       11               
95   img1455616291.jpg       11                
96   img1455617201.jpg       10                
97   img1455617299.jpg       10                
98   img1455681918.jpg       13              
99   img1455681957.jpg       12
```

this is my code to view image by clicking

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>roxcontrol/product_details/<?php echo $row->id; ?>/<?php echo $row->category_id; ?>">

   my category table is this..

    id  category_name   parent_id
    8   men             0
    9   kids            0
    10  T-shirts        8
    11  Shirts          8
    12  Jeans           8
    13  Pants           8
    14  Shorts          8
    15  Tees            9
    16  Shirts          9
    17  Jeans           9
    18  Pants           9
    19  Shorts & Ber    9
    20  Romper          9
```

my table contains shirts,tshirts,pants images and their corresponding category_ids are 10,11,12 when i choose the category_id=10 shirt image i want to get all category_id=10 shirt images under the related products and like that

the problem is category_id value is null iam not getting category_id value

Comment: where you are not getting id?

Comment: while we use the query in database to check if value is there or not

Comment: you want all images from gallery table of a category id from category table? if so follow my code below

Comment: print_r($id);die; before $data['detail']=$this->roxmodel->get_related_image($id,4,0); in your controller..i think id is not passed from input properly

Comment: 10 is t-shirts. What do you mean by 'and like that'?

Comment: that is 11 is shirt and pant is 12

Comment: @MOHAMMED try my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>roxcontrol/product_details/<?php echo $row->id; ?>/<?php echo $row->category_id; ?>">abc</a>
```

COntroller code should be for this

```
public function product_details($p_id, $category_id)
{
    $data['active_mn']='product_details';
    $data['product']=$this->roxmodel->get_product_details($p_id);
    $data['detail']=$this->roxmodel->get_related_image($category_id,4,0);
    var_dump($data['detail']);
    $this->load->view('product_details',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to fetch all images of a particular category id in category table.right??? if so change your model like this
Model

```
    public function get_related_image($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('gallery');
    $this->db->join('category','category.id=gallery.category_id');
    $this->db->where('category.id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Controller

```
 public function product_details($p_id)
{
    $data['active_mn']='product_details';
    $data['product']=$this->roxmodel->get_product_details($p_id);
    $data['detail']=$this->roxmodel->get_related_image($p_id);
    var_dump($data['detail']);
    $this->load->view('product_details',$data);
}
```

View

```
<input type="text" name="categoryid">
```

We are joined the two tables.so category name is also get in this result

```
echo $row->category_name;
```

Comment: @MOHAMMED are you there?

Comment: yaa..i changed but still same  i think the problem is at controler side

Comment: use $this->input->post('category_id'); instead of square bracket

Comment: done same like that...i think id is not passed from input properly how to clear this

Comment: you mean from view page?

Comment: i have updated. we are posting name of the field from view.see code above

Comment: where is your view page?

Comment: sorry internet was slow i had pasted my view page please see that

Comment: @MOHAMMED from where you posting category id? your view page is a display page right?\

Comment: $this->input->post('category_id'); i used this to get value from table

Comment: but in display page how can i give categoryid name

Comment: in your databes have category_id's names?

Comment: i will post my category table now

Comment: but we dont want category name.when we click on tshirt image i wnat to get all tshirt images and on clicking one shirt image i want all shirt images and so on

Comment: you have two tables right??? gallery and category. from which table your datas are displayed?

Comment: on the clicking link.pass the category id of that image.then fetch all images of that category from gallery table

Comment: see this    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>roxcontrol/product_details/<?php echo $row->id; ?>/<?php echo $row->category_id; ?>">

Comment: now we are moving on same way....now i wnt to fetch that images for that i need help

Comment: did you test id is getting on the controller? echo id?

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem...
Change where condition in your model

```
From:  $this->db->where('category_id',$id);
To(Change) : $this->db->where('category.id',$id);
```

Check Now....

Comment: print_r($id);die; when i use this nothing is coming..its die

Comment: ok...$this->input->post['category_id']; is not getting id actually so, print_r($_POST); and compare post fields...then let me know what happens

Comment: now its clear there is no category_id name..so to get what to do

Answer (score 0):

you are giving limit to

```
$this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
```

try

```
$this->db->limit($limit);
```